# Unconfigured {TAB} in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently creating an Excel spreadsheet with VBA macros. The thing is that I was trying to force a specific jump in cells when ENTER or TAB is pressed over this cells.

I don't know what happened but now, every time i press the TAB key, Excel prompts me a message saying "The macro Tab1 couldn't be found on: /PathOfTheWorksheet!Tab1"

This is the code I'm trying to use, but the message is still appearing.

```
Sub auto_open()
        Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "Tab1"
End Sub
Sub auto_close()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}"
End Sub
Sub Tab1()
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Formulario" Then
'Según la celda actual (posición inicial) elige la celda destino (posición final)
        Select Case ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)
            Case "J11": [J26].Activate
            Case "J16": [J11].Activate
            Case "J21": [J16].Activate
            Case "J26": [J21].Activate
'Si no está en ninguna celda de interés,
'se ubica en la celda contigua (si no está en la última columna)
            Case Else: If ActiveCell.Column <> Cells.Columns.Count Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        End Select
'Si no está en la hoja de trabajo hace lo 'normal'
    Else: If ActiveCell.Column <> Cells.Columns.Count Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Tab1` is a cell reference. Use a different name for the routine.

Comment: Thanks, it was straightforward but I didn't see it. All works now!

Comment: Not sure why Rory's answer works. I can create a Sub called Tab1 and it doesn't throw an error. So I don't see how that is the answer. Variatus's answer is very good. You break a lot of functionality by misusing TAB.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you found is quite ingenious, but I think it may not be exactly what you wanted. There is too much collateral damage. Please install the following code in the code sheet of your "Formulario" tab. You can delete it without ill effect on your workbook if it should disappoint you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Clm As Long = 10              ' specifies column J
    Dim Respondents, Targets
    Dim R As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .Column = 10 Then
            ' match sequence of 'Respondents' and 'Targets'
            Respondents = Array(11, 16, 21, 26)
            Targets = Array(0, 26, 11, 16, 21)
            ' the leading 0 in 'Targets' is insignificant but necessary:
            ' MATCH will find row 11 in the first position of 'Respondents'
            ' which is Targets(1) [= 26]

            On Error GoTo NotApplicable
            R = Targets(WorksheetFunction.Match(.Row, Respondents, 0))
            Cells(R, Clm).Select
        End If

NotApplicable:
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Firstly, this code will not run on any worksheet other than the one in whose code sheet you installed it, that is 'Formulario". Secondly, it will run when you click on any of the target cells (array `Targets`). Thirdly, it will not take any action when you click elsewhere and, fourthly, it will allow you to use the tab key for its usual purposes.

Comment: Hy @Variatus, thanks for the code. In fact my problem with the tab became due to the changes were effective after closing and opening again the worksheet (Sub auto_open()) there was my error. 
Anyway, my routine works perfectly and it does the same as yours. Therefore, I think it is only another solution for the same problem. In which way your routine improves mine? I make this question because I don't know why, not because I think that my routine is better than yours. ;-)

Comment: Your soluti0on is beautiful. But, in effect, it changes the way Excel works for all workbooks and all worksheets, and that makes it unprofessional. I thought about my solution after I posted it and thought it wasn't the best either because you would have difficulty editing the cells from which you wish to jump elsewhere. If you are interested I would program an improvement for you. But if you are happy with what you have  ... as I said, it's lovely.

Comment: Good to know @Variatus! Thanks for the information. Thanks for your offer, but it's not a big deal, it's just for a personal project. As my solution is working I will continue using it, but as I said, thanks for everything! It's a pleasure to share knowledge as here in www.stackoverflow.com